# Self-Expiring Enterprise App for In-House Distribution?

Tags: ios, ios6

I've been searching around and can't find out whether or not this is possible. There's been a request made to create an IPA with a "self-expiring provisioning profile that expires in 30 days". Is that even a possibility?

When I try to create a provisioning profile in the member center it does not give me the option to set when it expires.

Comment: I don't see any standard possibilities for it in my practice, but maybe Apple support can help you after special request=)

Comment: What's the purposes of this?

Comment: @JackyBoy Want to distribute a demo and make sure it doesn't work on the user's devices after a certain period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> an IPA with a "self-expiring provisioning profile that expires in 30 days".

The obvious solution is to save the date the first time the app is launched, check for that each time the app launches (or comes to the foreground, etc.), and refuse to do anything if the start date is more than 30 days before the current time.

The problem with that approach is that the user can always delete and reinstall the app, thus resetting the clock. To get around that, you'll need to save the first launch date for that device somewhere where it won't be deleted when the user deletes the app. That probably means sending the first launch date and some device identifier to your server. It's not bullet-proof -- the user can always turn off your network access so that you can't check in with your server -- but it's probably enough.

The next problem is choosing a way to identify the device (or the user). The UDID seems like an obvious choice, but it's deprecated and may go away at some point in the future. There are any number of alternatives to the UDID, but most of them still violate the spirit of the prohibition against using the UDID. Since you'll need to use a server anyway, you might want to think about having the user create an account on the server (through the app, of course) so that the start time is tied to the user account rather than the device.

Finally, you should be aware that this sort of thing will prevent your app from being approved in the App Store. Apps aren't supposed to stop working after a demo period expires. I know you said this is an enterprise app, but if that's the case it's hard to see why you'd need this kind of functionality anyway. You may be able to get around this, again, by making functionality depend on a user account on a server -- in that case you can suspend or terminate the user account to cut off access rather than having the app refuse to work.

If you want the app to expire after some period starting from when the app is built, that's a much simpler problem. Just store the build date (or expiration date) in some resource that's part of the app and periodically check against the current date.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the device to stop working after a certain amount of time:

```
#define BEGIN_DATE @"BEGIN_DATE"

    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:BEGIN_DATE])
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:BEGIN_DATE];
    };

    if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:BEGIN_DATE]] > 2592000)
    {
        *(long*)0 = 0xDEADBEEF;
    }
```

2592000 is one month in seconds.